# C++ Threaded Template Vector Quicksort

Tags: multithreading, vector, quicksort

Threaded quick sort method:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "MD5.h"
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void quickSort(vector<T> &arr, int left, int right) {
    int i = left, j = right; //Make local copys to modify
    T tmp; //Termorary variable to use for swaping.
    T pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2]; //Find the centerpoint. if 0.5 truncate.

    while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[i] < pivot) //is i < pivot?
            i++;
        while (arr[j] > pivot) //Is j > pivot?
            j--;
        if (i <= j) {          //Swap
            tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    };

    thread left_t; //Left thread
    thread right_t; //Right thread
    if (left < j)
        left_t = thread(quickSort<T>, ref(arr), left, j);

    if (i < right)
        right_t = thread(quickSort<T>, ref(arr), i, right);

    if (left < j)
        left_t.join();
    if (left < j)
        right_t.join();
}


int main()
{
    vector<int> table;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        table.push_back(rand() % 100);
    }
    cout << "Before" << endl;
    for each(int val in table)
    {
        cout << val << endl;
    }
    quickSort(table, 0, 99);
    cout << "After" << endl;
    for each(int val in table)
    {
        cout << val << endl;
    }
    char temp = cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Above program lags like mad hell and Spams "abort()" has been called.

Im thinking it has something to do with vectors and it Having threading issues

Iv seen the Question asked by Daniel Makardich, His Utilizes a Vector int While mine uses Vector T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any problem with quick sort, but with passing a templated function to a thread. There is no function `quickSort`. You need to explicitly give type, to instantiate the function template:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void f(T a) { std::cout << a << '\n'; }

int main () {
    std::thread t;
    int a;
    std::string b("b");
    t = std::thread(f, a); // Won't work
    t = std::thread(f<int>, a);
    t.join();
    t = std::thread(f<decltype(b)>, b); // a bit fancier, more dynamic way
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I suspect in your case this should do:

```
left_t = thread(quickSort<T>, ref(arr), left, j);
```

And similar for `right_t`. Also, you have mistake there trying to use `operator()()` instead of constructing an object. That is why the error is different.

Can't verify though, cause there's no minimal verifiable example =/

I don't know if it's possible to make compiler to use automatic type deduction for `f` passed as a param, if anyone knows that would probably make it a better answer.

Comment: K Now it seems to abort. Probably a concurrent modification exception?

Comment: Yes, you need to `join`, or otherwise take care of each constructed thread (I think the only other option is to detach) after cppreference: "*(destructor): destructs the thread object, underlying thread must be joined or detached*".

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with thread joins and what @luk32 said

Needed to convert the threads to pointers to threads.

```
thread* left_t = nullptr; //Left thread
thread* right_t = nullptr; //Right thread
if (left < j)
    left_t = new thread(quickSort<T>, ref(arr), left, j);

if (i < right)
    right_t = new thread(quickSort<T>, ref(arr), i, right);

if (left_t)
{
    left_t->join();
    delete left_t;
}
if (right_t)
{
    right_t->join();
    delete right_t;
}
```

Seems like if you create a default constructed thread object. But don't use it, it still wants to be joined. and if you do join it, it will complain.